# Proof by induction that $2 + 4 + 6 + \cdots + 2n = n(n+1)$

Tags: proof-writing, induction

Proving by induction. We'd like to show that
$2 + 4 + 6 + \cdots+ 2n = n(n + 1)$.

A nice way to do this is by induction. Let $S(n)$ be the statement above. An inductive proof would have the following steps:
 Show that $S(1)$ is true.
 Show that if $S(1),\ldots,S(k)$ are true, then so is $S(k + 1)$.

---

This question is really starting to bug me, am I doing something wrong or is the equation wrong for that series? It only seems to work for $S(1)$ but after that it does not give the correct series. The $n(n+1)$ series is $2, 6, 12,\ldots.$ I'm really confused can someone please nudge me in the right direction (I know how proofs by induction works) I'm just having problems with this one in particular.

Comment: $2+4=6$ and $2+4+6=12$... Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, that answer is correct. If you note that $2+4+6+...+2n = 2*(1+2+3+...+n)=2 \frac{n*(n+1)}2 = n*(n+1)$

Second. Suppose that it is true, you have $2+4+6+...+2n = n*(n+1)$ This is $S(n)$
add 2(n+1) to both sides, giving
$$2+4+...+2n+2(n+1) = n*(n+1) + 2(n+1) = (n+2)(n+1)$$ which is $S(n+1)$

Answer (score 1):

If $S(k)$ is true, we have $\sum_{i=1}^k2i=k(k+1)$  Then we want to evaluate $\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}2i=\sum_{i=1}^k2i+2(k+1)=k(k+1)+2(k+1)=(k+2)(k+1)$ so $S(k+1)$ is true.

Answer (score 1):

Base case: $n=1$

$2=1(1+1)=2$

Assume true for $n=k$, that is:

$2+4+6+...+2k=k(k+1)$

To show true for $n=k+1$

$2+4+6+...+2k+2(k+1)=k(k+1)+2(k+1)=(k+1)(k+2)=(k+1)(k+1+1)$

Hence, $2+4+6+...+2n=n(n+1)$

The equation is correct. It is just a simple arithmetic series. If you can remember a formula for an arithmetic series given by $S_n=\frac{n(a_1+a_n)}{2}$. In this case the first term is $2$ the last term is $2n$ and the number of terms is $n$ so we have:

$$S_n=\frac{n(2+2n)}{2}=\frac{2n(1+n)}{2}=n(n+1)$$

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to explain this in plain English.

Problem statement: 2+4+6+...+2n = n(n+1)

The statement can be broken down into 3 parts.

a) The portion on the left-hand side of the = sign, before the ... i.e. 2+4+6, which represents a sequence of numbers.

b) The portion of the left-hand side of the = sign, after the ... i.e. 2n, which is used to calculate the element of the sequence at the index n. Note the sequence is 1 based, not 0 based.

c) Everything on the right-hand side of the = sign, i.e. n(n+1), which is used to sum up all elements within the sequence.

Consider the following when n=5

2n = 2*5 = 10, therefore the sequence can be written as 2+4+6+?+10.

Note the 4th element of the sequence is currently unknown, which isn't an impediment, as it can be resolved later using elementary arithmetic.

Use the formula on the right-hand side of the = sign, to sum together all elements within the sequence, including the unknown values as follows: 
n(n+1) = 5(5+1) = 5*6 = 30.

Then use basic algebra to find the missing element at index 4: 
2+4+6+?+10 = 30 
22+?=30
?=30-22
?=8

Therefore, the resulting sequence is 2+4+6+8+10

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Please try to incorporate use of mathjax in you posts.

Comment: @amWhy. Apologies, will do in future